# URL's creating Duplicate Content best practices?

Tags: url, url-rewrite

I am using the Community Edition and recently started working on Magento on a site that has been live for 3.5 years. I noticed that in Google Analytics, I am getting 2 different results on the CMS Page

"www.baseurl.com/cms-page" and "www.baseurl.com/cms-page/"

I also noticed that the CMS pages do not have a .html like the products, is that normal? Is there a code I can drop into the .htacess to just reroute the URLS from "/cms-page/" to "/cms-page"? Or should I look at an SEO plugin? The CMS pages have interlinks as well that do not have consistency, so before I go in and do everything by hand...

What are the best practices here and best fix? Thank you.

Current Rewrite Rules and Conditions

```
############################################
## enable rewrites

# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#    Options +FollowSymLinks
    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Yep, CMS pages without the '.html' at the end are normal.  You can add them in to the admin if you like CMS -> Pages -> open specific page -> URL Key, but this isn't really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Add an .htaccess rule to 301 redirect any page without a trailing slash.  The `RewriteRule` below will exclude html, html, jpg, gif, png and pdf so it won't add a trailing slash where it isn't needed.  You can add to the types in the parentheses in the `RewriteCond` to include more file extensions.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(htm|html|jpg|gif|png|pdf)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will test it tomorrow. Beer time right now.

Comment: Ok, I did it and I really did not know where to put it. It also sent the urls to the index.php. There are some rewrite rules already in there. I am guessing this is conflicting somewhere. I updated the original question with the current rules that were in there.

Comment: You should be able to put it at the very bottom of your htaccess

Comment: when I do that, it sends every link to www.website.com/index.php